# imagePickerController move and scale does not work

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Here is my code:

```
-(void) takePhoto
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    //imagePickerController.editing = YES;
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing=YES;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

#pragma mark - Image picker delegate methods
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    [self.Picture setImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];


}
```

and I have implemented the delegates

```
UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
```

The image is taken, I can see the move and scale box, but when I move it the box returns to the initial position - likes it bounces back.

Why is that?

Comment: I have this exact issue as well with the same implementation. 99% convinced it's an Apple bug.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is caused because you are requesting the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`, according to the documentation this returns "the original, uncropped image selected by the user."

Try changing this to `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Information_Keys

Edit: Actually after re-reading the question a couple of times if the problem is occurring in the picker itself this probably won't help.